# Got "Unable to find PDF file header" when using pfdi to generate a pdf from multiple pdf file

Tags: php, pdf, prestashop

I'm trying to create a pdf inside a prestashop php module.

When generating the pdf file from my olds pdf urls, it works in local on my computer but when installed on a server it give me the error **"Unable to find PDF file header."**

I checked if the file exist, if permissions are ok and if the file is readable but everything seems ok

```
            # Loop through every pdf url
            foreach ($order->export_invoice_url as $page=>$link) {
                $path = __DIR__ . '/data/pdf.pdf';

                file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($link));
                $pdf->setSourceFile($path);

                unlink($path);
                $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, null, null, true);
            }
```

Could there be something wrong ?

I tried to store the file to another path and to get the pdf files from a stream instead of a downloaded file but i got the same problem

Comment: so, at this stage:
file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($link));

your file exists and is available on the server?

Comment: Yes the file exist.
I think that's a problem about permissions and php parameters that differ between websites.
I found another solution that is a redirection to te pdf url without editing it